# Can i use iphone's wifi to comunicate with my own wifi module?

Tags: iphone, sdk, wifi

Including data exchange. I can not find such api in apple doc site. If it is not open in 3.1.2 sdk ,would apple release it in sdk4.0? I've heared that google released wireless api on android earlier . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

iPhones support ad-hoc wifi networking, so I expect you can make your device start an ad-hoc network and have the iPhone user connect manually.  I doubt there will be an API for that, it's a security issue.

Comment: If your device can do ad-hoc like the phone, then just tell it to do ad-hoc and the two devices will be on the same network. 
It's then a network programming task.  So data exchange then via whatever you want: http is already on the phone so that would be easy. Pop a web server on whatever's running your wifi module.